# css: rotate elements issue

Tags: html, css, transformation

I'm trying to rotate two elements in a very simple setting

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The parent element has the css perspective property and on the children I do the transformation

```
#parent {
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;
    -moz-perspective: 800px;
    perspective: 800px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 24px;
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 1px;
}
.child {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 66deg );
    -moz-transform: rotateY( 66deg );
    transform: rotateY( 66deg );
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin:10px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

( [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vPgF/2/) )
What I don't understand is that the second child is rotated correctly, but the first is not. Its top is horizontal and not rotated. Any suggestions why this is happening ?

Comment: Can you post the code to rotate the children?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri why are you using perspective for one and rotate for the others?

Comment: no thing in opera 12.16

Comment: @agconti The correct way to use perspective is to set it on the father and transform the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because rotateY uses 3d perspective.

try this in your HTML and it should become clear:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

For me on Firefox, it even changes the color of the rectangles.

Comment: found the explanation [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/) and [here](http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/)